# CSS Overlay with php mysql info

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, css

So just like the title says, I want to create an CSS overlay and within the overlay I want to show info retrieved from an SQL database using PHP.

I just don't know where to start..

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the below 3 steps.

1) Prepare your data first

What i mean is get all the required data from mysql and format it and keep it ready.

2) Write CSS/HTML for getting the overlay functionality. This link will help you with that.
   http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/content_overlay_css

3) The data that you have prepared in step 1, echo it in the overlay box.

Answer (score 0):

There are two unrelated parts to this: retrieving the data with PHP (a server-side issue) and coding and styling some HTML (a front end / browser issue). Perhaps break this up into tow stages. First work out how to retrieve the data, and then later look into how to present it in a browser.